# Issues building vips library from go

Tags: macos, go, vips

I am trying to run/build a GoLang package that uses vips. When I try to compile the program I get this error:
`go build gopkg.in/h2non/bimg.v1: invalid flag in pkg-config --cflags: -Xpreprocessor`

Here are my specs:

```
macOS Mojave Version 10.14.3
vips Version 8.7.4
go Version 1.11.5 darwin/amd64
```

I read some issues adding CGOALLOWEDFLAGS I've tried that also but no luck.

Comment: [https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InvalidFlag](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InvalidFlag)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CFLAGS` is extra flags to give to the C compiler. (commonly used in *make*, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)

The [gopkg.in/h2non/bimg.v1/vips.go](https://github.com/h2non/bimg/blob/v1.0.19/vips.go#L4) uses `pkg-config` to generate the extra flags. It has [`-Xpreprocessor`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) flag, which is not allowed by CGo (by default at the time of writing this).

> For security reasons, only a limited set of flags are allowed, notably `-D`, `-I`, and `-l`. To allow additional flags, set `CGO_CFLAGS_ALLOW` to a regular expression matching the new flags. To disallow flags that would otherwise be allowed, set `CGO_CFLAGS_DISALLOW` to a regular expression matching arguments that must be disallowed. In both cases the regular expression must match a full argument: to allow `-mfoo=bar`, use `CGO_CFLAGS_ALLOW='-mfoo.*'`, not just `CGO_CFLAGS_ALLOW='-mfoo'`. (See: https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

To allow `-Xpreprocessor`, you can set `CGO_CFLAGS_ALLOW=-Xpreprocessor`.
For example:

```
CGO_CFLAGS_ALLOW=-Xpreprocessor go vet ./...
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation! I've got it working.